# How to overcome mismatched tag error in python feedparser module

Tags: python, xml, feedparser

I am using the python feedparse.py module version 5.2.1.  trying to read feeds from usnews, for example https://www.usnews.com/rss/the-report. I get an xml file with the rss 2.0 header

feedparser returns 'status': 403, 'encoding': 'us-ascii', 'bozo_exception': SAXParseException('mismatched tag',), 'version': ''

Status 403 seems to be a request error but the exception provided is a parser error. I like to know if there is a workaround this error (such as changing the parser 'strictness'

Thank you

```
import feedparser
f = feedparser.parse('https://www.usnews.com/rss/news/the-run-2016',
                 agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36')
```

Above is the simplest example exhibiting the error. I have been using feedparser.py for months in a production application, it was just with example and all the feeds at usnews.com where I encountered the error. Thank you for having a look.

The error is shown below:

```
{'feed': {}, 'entries': [], 'bozo': 1, 'headers': {'Server': 'AkamaiGHost', 'Mime-Version': '1.0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '301', 'Expires': 'Tue, 29 Jan 2019 17:10:37 GMT', 'Date': 'Tue, 29 Jan 2019 17:10:37 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Origin': 'AWS-Brightspot', 'Set-Cookie': 'akacd_www=2177452799~rv=31~id=6f8f4ecea09b9abd4835d9ddd7c87ac8; path=/; Expires=Mon, 31 Dec 2038 23:59:59 GMT'}, 'href': 'https://www.usnews.com/rss/news/the-run-2016', 'status': 403, 'encoding': 'us-ascii', 'bozo_exception': SAXParseException('mismatched tag',), 'version': '', 'namespaces': {}}
```

news ---

Also, The xml is quickly parsed by my browsers.

Comment: You overcome it by fixing the XML.  There is no notion of strictness.  Either the textual data is well-formed XML, or it is not.

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. :)

Comment: That's good, but the MVCE doesn't demonstrate the error, at least presenting it. perhaps add a `print(r)` line? But yes, the error is in the response. (I know, it's a minor quibble.)

Answer (score 1):

Without digging to deep into what's actually happening here (this is likely a feedparser issue or a returned encoding issue), the inclusion of `agent` in your feedparser instance is the culprit here. Using:

```
import feedparser
f = feedparser.parse('https://www.usnews.com/rss/news/the-run-2016')
```

seems to alleviate your issue here. As to the why, that deserves a bit more research.

Comment: That works! .. I have used a user agent for hundreds of other feeds, in fact without the agent some feeds fail. But that can be worked around. Thank you for checking the obvious Chris Larson.

Comment: @JackMullen You bet! It's a puzzle, and I'm going to try to figure out what's actually happening here, but thought offering this solution as is was probably expedient. :) Could you mark the answer as accepted? That would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, yet I'm not including agent...